# Random Number Generation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, random, sql-server-2012

I Need to generate a random number between two numbers for each row.

For Eg:

select ColName,***(Random nos between 1500 to 2000)*** from TableName

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @start INT
DECLARE @end INT

SET @start = 1500
SET @end = 2000

SELECT  Round(( ( @end - @start - 1 ) * Rand() + @start ), 0)
```

**Update :**  To get random number for each row.

```
select ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % (@end-@start)) + @start
```

Comment: I need a random number for each row.. this will not generate different values for each row

Comment: a little change required

Comment: @VigneshM - Check now.

Comment: NewId() contains some interlocked threaded variables I prefer to use getdate and @@packet_received in order to have random numbers: `rand(@@spid+ @@PACK_RECEIVED + datepart(microsecond,getdate()) )`

Answer (score 6):

Random number formula is

**RANDOM DECIMAL RANGE**

```
SELECT RAND()*(b-a)+a;
```

**Example**

```
SELECT RAND()*(25-10)+10; // Random between 10 to 25
```

**RANDOM INTEGER RANGE**

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(b-a)+a);
```

**Example**

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10)+10);
```

Comment: You have to use `FLOOR` or `ROUND` or `CEILING` function for avoiding the decimal part.

Answer (score 1):

a little change required, by replacing the following code it will respond.

```
 Round(( ( @end - @start - 1 ) * Rand(checksum(newid())) + @start ), 0)
```

Eg:

**Generate Same Value :**

`select top 10 ROUND(((2000 - 1500 -1) * RAND() + 1500), 0)` from sysobjects

**Generate Different Value :**

`select top 10 ROUND(((2000 - 1500 -1) * Rand(checksum(newid()))+ 1500), 0)` from sysobjects

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND(((2000 - 1500 -1) * RAND() + 1500), 0)
```